# wireless card that supports Lubuntu 17.04 out of the box?

Tags: wireless, usb, lubuntu

What usb card supports Lubuntu 17.04 out of the box with wireless g, and wireless n capabilities. I want something that just works because I'm having all sorts of issues with my current one. Suggestions please?

Comment: Many wireless cards require tweeking to get them fully operational. Why not tell us what's going on with your current wireless config, and maybe we can fix that for you. And... if you do get a different USB wireless dongle, you should be looking for one that's AC compatible now a days.

Comment: Well what is something that you would recommend that works without a wired connection to setup, as one is not available. I'm just looking for compatibility, what's ac and made to be compatible?

Comment: Wireless AC is the latest standard, and is backwards compatible w/bgn. AC is a more robust protocol. I don't know that anybody can safely recommend a wireless dongle that's guaranteed to work 100% out of the box with Linux/Ubuntu. That's why, if your current wireless is working, but having some trouble, that you troubleshoot/repair that first.